# Exception in client breeze.js when using enum property on model

Tags: enums, breeze

The only thing I could find about enum support in breeze.js is [this feature suggestion](https://breezejs.uservoice.com/forums/173093-breeze-feature-suggestions/suggestions/3324099-support-for-enum-properties-on-entities) on uservoice, which was recently marked as closed in 0.82.
I'm using currently latest, 0.84.3.

**UPDATE:**
I'm using code first in EF 5.0.0 with .net 4.5. When starting application and breeze makes request for metadata, EF creates empty database and my enum property is in database as int, so that part is ok.

However, when I added an enum property to my model, I got exception when breeze tried to parse metadata:

```
Uncaught Error: Unable to locate an 'Type' by the name: ItemType:#TestApp.Models breeze.debug.js:5051
getTypeFromMap breeze.debug.js:5051
ctor.getEntityType breeze.debug.js:5028
ctor._updateProperty breeze.debug.js:6056
ctor._fixup breeze.debug.js:6133
ctor._fixup breeze.debug.js:6132
ctor.addEntityType breeze.debug.js:4702
convertFromODataEntityType
```

This is my model (simplified):

```
public enum ItemType
  {
    Ordered,
    Approved,
    Misc
  }

public class Item 
  {

    public long Id { get; set; }

    public ItemType Type { get; set; }

  }
```

Where am I making mistake? Is there working sample with enum?

Comment: What version of Entity Framework ( and .NET) are you using and is your model Code First or Database First? This information helps us to try to repro your issue.

Comment: I edited my question to include that information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just tried adding your ItemType enum to one of our models ( the ToDo model in the breeze DocCode sample) without a problem.

I am not sure what you are running into.  So two suggestions,

1) Try updating (hack) the DocCode sample that ships within the breeze samples zip to use your  ItemType enum ( details below) and then run any of the basic ToDo tests.

```
// In DocCode/Models/ToDoItem.cs
namespace Todo.Models 
{
    public class TodoItem 
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }                     // 42

        [Required, StringLength(maximumLength: 30)]     // Validation rules
        public string Description { get; set; }         // "Get milk"

        public System.DateTime CreatedAt { get; set; }  // 25 August 2012, 9am PST
        public bool IsDone { get; set; }                // false
        public bool IsArchived { get; set; }            // false
        // YOUR ENUM PROPERTY
        public ItemType Type { get; set; }
    }

    // YOUR ENUM TYPE
    public enum ItemType {
      Ordered,
      Approved,
      Misc
    }

}

// In DocCode/Models/ToDoDatabaseInitializer
private static TodoItem CreateTodo(string description, bool isDone, bool isArchived)
{
    _baseCreatedAtDate = _baseCreatedAtDate.AddMinutes(1);
    return new TodoItem
    {
        CreatedAt = _baseCreatedAtDate,
        Description = description,
        IsDone = isDone,
        IsArchived = isArchived,
        // YOUR ENUM PROPERTY
        Type = ItemType.Ordered
    };
}
```

or

2) Send me (Jay Traband) a stripped down version of your project at breeze@ideablade.com.

Comment: Thanks, I found the problem by trying to reproduce it on sample. Basically, when I added enum to sample, I noticed that it is not sent through metadata, and I have exception when metadata is parsed. So, I cleared cache :) The problem I had was the Type property was sent in metadata as complex property, and I did not know what it should look like. When I saw that there shouldn't be there, I figured that I have cached metadata from version where Type was EF discriminator for Table Per Type Hierarchy, and I changed that to single type with enum, as I had problems with deeper inheritance & breeze.

Comment: And sorry for wasting your time!

Comment: No problem! Feedback like this helps us improve our docs. Not clearing the cache bites me regularly.

Comment: Aah, I was wrong, it was not the metadata cache. When I refreshed it, the enum type was missing because I declared it inside class, because it denotes type of instance of that class, so I figured to encapsulate it. That, however, causes EF to ignore this property, so that is why I thought issue is solved, but I noticed later that there is no property. After debugging how TODO sample works, I determined that VS did not properly updated breeze js files, there were differences between files in my project and in sample. I copied them and it works now!