# Deleting an entity with a modified enum property with Breeze

Tags: breeze

I have an issue when I am trying to delete an entity that also has a modified enum property. The error i get is **Invalid cast from 'System.String' to 'BV.Entities.CarType'**. A simple example follows:

```
public class Car {
  public int Id { get; set; }
  public CarType Type { get; set; } // CarType is an enum
}

var car = // load a car entity
car.Type('Sedan');
car.entityAspect.setDeleted();
manager.saveChanges();
```

This can happen, for example, when a user starts editing a record, but then decides to just delete it.

I have also used the DocCode sample to test this. I edited the saveTodoTests.js and used the 'can save add, update, and delete in one batch' test similar to what was suggested here [Exception in client breeze.js when using enum property on model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14308529/exception-in-client-breeze-js-when-using-enum-property-on-model). If I alter the enum type of the deleteTodo item it throws the error, if I remove the setDeleted() it will save it correctly.

```
System.InvalidCastException was unhandled by user code
  HResult=-2147467262
  Message=Invalid cast from 'System.String' to 'BV.Entities.CarType'.
  Source=mscorlib
  StackTrace:
       at System.Convert.DefaultToType(IConvertible value, Type targetType, IFormatProvider provider)
       at System.String.System.IConvertible.ToType(Type type, IFormatProvider provider)
       at System.Convert.ChangeType(Object value, Type conversionType, IFormatProvider provider)
       at Breeze.ContextProvider.EF6.EFContextProvider`1.ConvertValue(Object val, Type toType)
       at Breeze.ContextProvider.EF6.EFContextProvider`1.SetPropertyValue(Object entity, String propertyName, Object value)
       at Breeze.ContextProvider.EF6.EFContextProvider`1.<>c__DisplayClass10.<RestoreOriginal>b__f(KeyValuePair`2 kvp)
       at System.Collections.Generic.List`1.ForEach(Action`1 action)
       at Breeze.ContextProvider.EF6.EFContextProvider`1.RestoreOriginal(EntityInfo entityInfo)
       at Breeze.ContextProvider.EF6.EFContextProvider`1.<ProcessAllDeleted>b__9(EFEntityInfo entityInfo)
       at System.Collections.Generic.List`1.ForEach(Action`1 action)
       at Breeze.ContextProvider.EF6.EFContextProvider`1.ProcessAllDeleted(List`1 deletedEntities)
       at Breeze.ContextProvider.EF6.EFContextProvider`1.SaveChangesCore(SaveWorkState saveWorkState)
       at Breeze.ContextProvider.ContextProvider.OpenAndSave(SaveWorkState saveWorkState)
       at Breeze.ContextProvider.ContextProvider.SaveChanges(JObject saveBundle, TransactionSettings transactionSettings)
       at BV.Web.Controllers.DefaultController.SaveChanges(JObject saveBundle) in c:\Work\Code\BV\BV.Web\Controllers\DefaultController.cs:line 59
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, this was a bug and is fixed in the combination of the current breeze.server.net and breeze.js repos on GitHub.  It will also go out as part of the next release (1.4.14) sometime next week.